# Why does on_command_error fire when I have already ignored a message that is a bad command?

Tags: command, discord, bots, discord.py

I have the following 2 listeners in the sole cog for my bot:

```
@Cog.listener()
async def on_command_error(self, ctx, error)  :
    if isinstance(error, CommandNotFound):
        await ctx.send_help()

@Cog.listener()
async def on_message(self, message):
    if message.author.bot:
        return
    if message.content.startswith(">--"):
        return
```

The command prefix is `>-`, and I was under the impression that the `return` for messages starting with `>--` would mean that the message goes no further than `on_message`, yet when I give the command `>--halp`, `on_command_error` fires with the error:

```
CommandNotFound('Command "-halp" is not found')
```

Is my understanding of how to ignore messages fault, or does `on_command_error` even fire for "dead" messages, or what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Registering a listener inside of a cog does not replace the default one used by the bot (if a default exists).

In your case, every time a message is sent to a channel the bot can see, both the custom `on_message` event in the cog as well as the default `on_message` event will trigger.

This is why the `CommandNotFound` error is raised, since the default `on_message` event still tries to process the message and check if a command was called.

If you override the default `on_message` event in your main file (where your bot client is defined), then both custom `on_message` events will still trigger (the main and the cog).

This can be verified with the below. When the bot sees a message, both `bot.py` and `cog.py` will be printed, indicating both `on_message` events are triggered.

**bot.py**

```
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='>-')

client.load_extension('cog')

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    print('bot.py')
    await client.process_commands(message)

client.run('TOKEN')
```

**cog.py**

```
from discord.ext import commands

class TestCog(commands.Cog):
    
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, message):
        print('cog.py')

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(TestCog(bot))
```

If you want the bot to completely ignore certain messages, then you need to do so in a custom `on_message` event in the file where the bot client is defined.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by a "custom" `on_message` in the file where the client is defined. You've just told me both the cog's and the "bot file's" `on_message` will fire. Or by _custom_ do you mean a lower level listener closer to actual; request/response operations?

Comment: When creating a bot it will already have an `on_message` event by default. You can override this by creating a custom one in the bot's file. In this case, only the custom `on_message` event will fire.